# SB 10.88: Why does Supreme lord's devotees lives in poverty?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, moksha

I don't understand this. Please someone explain me. Why does the devotees of Supreme Lord live in poverty. What if one devotees doesn't want to attain moksha. Will lord forcefully attract him towards it? That means the free will will be ruined that way. Why does a devotee of Supreme Lord cannot live the life of his desire?

Comment: no, the Lord never forces anyone to strive to attain Him. Where exactly lies your confusion?

Comment: @sahadev please Read SB 10.88 then, I have this question: If I worship him for material desires, will he take it away from me after sometime?

Comment: @Kartik he wont take it.... everything is temporary in this world. Whatever you possess today, one day it will go off. What you think as necessity today, may not be important tomorrow. This is Dharma of this world. And at this age, you cant understand real meanings of Bhagavad Gita.... Give yourself sometime..... Just stay good boy !!! That's it for now! Dont think too much!! Or if you're longing to know this, this is not a place for it!!!!

Comment: I have read the purport and the explanation is horrible according to Śrīla Prabhupāda: he on purposely lets you suffer so that god can arise as a savior to give you pleasure.

Comment: @Kartik if you're lucky, then yes He will take away your material desires